# Lower bound of continuous random walk

Tags: lower-bounds, random-walks

Let $X_1,...X_T$ be i.i.d. random variables supported on the $[-1,1]$ segment, with an expected value of 0 and positive variance.

Let $H_t = | \sum_{i=1}^t X_i|$, and let $H = \max_{1\leq t\leq T} H_t$.

I'm interested in lower bounds on $\mathbb E[H_T]$ and $\mathbb E[H]$.

Any ideas?

---

Using Jensen's inequality, upper bounds are easier to get (at least for $\mathbb E[H_T]$). But what about lower bounds?

I know that if $X_i$ is Rademacher ($\pm 1$ with equal probability), then $\mathbb E[Y] = \Theta(\sqrt T)$, see here ([Discrepancy between heads and tails](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/discrepancy-between-heads-and-tails)). However, the construction in that reference uses specific properties of the Rademacher distribution, whereas here we have the general case ($X_i$ can take any bounded distribution).

I know that the [law of iterated algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) might be of use, but I have no idea how to derive a finite sample concentration.

Edit:
If the distribution of $X_i$ is symmetric, we can perhaps use [Khintchine's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality). But I could not figure this out too.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if the math works out, but did you try to use CLT for $\mathbb E[H_T]$ (and then use that for the normal distribution the answer is $\Theta(\sigma \sqrt{T})$ IIRC)? In particular, [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) seems to give good convergence rate.

Comment: If I understand the suggestion of using CLT, it is equivalent to assuming that $X_i$ are i.i.d. with Normal distribution. I'm not sure that's easier :) Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I suggest using the CLT to approximate $\sum X_i$. Basically, $\sum X_i$ is distributed close to the normal distribution with variance $\Theta(\sigma \sqrt{T})$, and the Berry-Esseen theorem bounds how close they are. For the normal distribution, [we know the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

Comment: (BTW, if $X_i$ are normal, then $\sum X_i$ is also normal, and then for $\mathbb E[H_T]$ you can just apply the result for the normal distribution)

Comment: @Dmitry the Berry-Esseen theorem doesn't seem to help (at least I cannot make it work). For the lower bound, I'm integrating $\Phi(x)-F_n(x)$ between 0 and $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$. Taking the global upper bound seems to be too much and we get a negative result. Is there a bound over the integral (rather than over the integrand)?

Comment: Namely, using Berry-Esseen inequality (bounds the supremum) to bound the integral of $\Phi (x)- F_n(x)$ is too crude.